# How to align two text view horizontally with background using any layout in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout

I am using two text views with background and I want to align both text views side by side with some margin between them. I have tried this code but it does not work well with smaller devices.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_back"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_green_1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:paddingTop="3dip"
                    android:paddingBottom="3dip"
                    android:text="Save &amp; Close"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:minLines="2"/>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_next"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_green_1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minLines="2"
                    android:paddingTop="3dip"
                    android:paddingBottom="3dip"
                    android:text="@string/label_next_shipping_method"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: By looking at Image i think you mean vertically . set `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to `LinearLayout` .

Comment: to your parent layout-> android:layout_gravity="center"

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code, it is quite fine, but some changes are required to get the layout you want.

Just add  `android:gravity="center"` to your `LinearLayout`

Remove `android:layout_gravity="top"` and `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"` from 'textviews`

Try below code, In below code I'm add `View` and change `android:layout_weight` for making layout more responsive.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_weight=".03"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".45"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_green_1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="3dip"
        android:paddingBottom="3dip"
        android:text="Save &amp; Close"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:minLines="2"/>
    <View
        android:layout_weight=".04"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".45"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_green_1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:text="Next - Select Shipping \nMethod"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
    <View
        android:layout_weight=".03"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Output is like below image:

[image]

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `LinearLayout`:

```py
android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your height in textview from `wrap_content` to `match_parent` so the two will have the same size. You can set the height of the LinearLayout to `wrap_content` too

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" ... />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" ... />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and re-write it for you, try below code that might help you to solve your problem

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_green_1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="Save &amp; Close"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_green_1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:text="@string/label_next_shipping_method"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code as below, and your problem solved!

```html
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:background="#CCCCCC">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_back"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingTop="3dip"
            android:paddingBottom="3dip"
            android:text="Save &amp; Close"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_next"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:paddingTop="3dip"
            android:paddingBottom="3dip"
            android:text="Next - Select Shipping Method Method Method"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I set my own background so you just set your own.

This is the result:

[image: the result image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code. It will solve your issue. If you face any issue then please let me know in comment section.

Use your own drawables and assests.

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:text="Total Optional Service:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_optional_service_amount"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:text="$18.00"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_back"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorBlack"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:text="Save &amp; Close"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_next"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorBlack"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:text="Next - Select Shipping Method"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please approve answer if it will work for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_back"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_green_1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Save &amp; Close"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_next"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_green_1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/label_next_shipping_method"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the other answers are good and some may solve your problem
**(@Android Geek answer, for example, is really well made)**
, but none of them mentioned [constraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) so I want to offer another solution.

---

Before we begin, let me explain why I want to add constraintLayout solution and not just use `LinearLayout` as mentioned :

When you use `LinearLayout` with nested views inside them and in addition using `android:layout_weight` and `android:weightSum` attributes you may find that your layouts performance got affected (although in this case with only 2 views it won't affect your layout ).
This may happen because more calculation are needed in order to display all of your nested views.

---

Ok, let's get into the code - using constraintLayout you can simply use [chain](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html) between 2 views:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="Save"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="Next"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And get your wanted result:

[image]

---

Now, if you already passed all of the above in the answer you may be wondering - maybe I will stay with `LinearLayout`, well, you can and it will be your decision but here are some advantages of `ConstraintLayout`:

- Your layout will be responsive to all screen sizes so no need to create a layout for every screen size.
- Making the layout is by far faster with `ConstraintLayout`, it can save a lot of time.
- On almost all cases  your layout performance will be better compared to the same layout made with `LinearLayout`

---

So happy coding, I hope that this answer can be helpful and if you have any questions feel free to comment and ask.

Comment: This looks good but I don't want to use "Button" tag. Please, let me know if you have created this using "TextView".

Comment: You can create it with any kind of view that you want, this was juat an example. Feel free to change it

Comment: Thanks a lot. You did a great job.

Comment: If this helped you please accept the answer so it can help others.